# Postgresql aggregate a json column to get any row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate, psql

I have a query in `psql` which returns a column of type json

```
SELECT PC.cid, json_object_agg(PC.pid, PC.map)
FROM process_table AS PC
WHERE PC.pid=240 OR PC.pid=63
GROUP BY PC.cid
```

Which returns correctly:

```
cid |  json_object_agg
---------+--------------------
  625144 | { "63" : "gfff" }
  665087 | { "63" : "sdfg" }
  721472 | { "63" : "qerdd" }
  756135 | { "63" : "dasdfg" }
 2262581 | { "63" : "fgyhh" }
```

I want to join another table to this which has a many-to-many relationship. i.e. `cid` is no longer unique and will have duplicate `json_object_agg` rows.

```
SELECT F.cid, COUNT(SC.sid)
    FROM (
        SELECT PC.cid, json_object_agg(PC.pid, PC.map)
        FROM process_table AS PC
        WHERE PC.pid=240 OR PC.pid=63
        GROUP BY PC.cid
    ) AS F
INNER JOIN system_tables_2 as SC ON SC.cid=F.cid
GROUP BY F.cid
```

**How can I output a single  `json_object_agg` for each `F.cid`? Does not matter which one since they are all the same.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Can you share a sample on db-fiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an aggregate function like `MAX` or `MIN` on the JSON object, like below

```
 SELECT F.cid, MAX(F.json_object) AS json_object, COUNT(SC.sid)
    FROM (
        SELECT PC.cid, json_object_agg(PC.pid, PC.map) AS json_object
        FROM process_table AS PC
        WHERE PC.pid=240 OR PC.pid=63
        GROUP BY PC.cid
    ) AS F
    INNER JOIN system_tables_2 as SC ON SC.cid = F.cid
    GROUP BY F.cid;
```